# Autoware :1.12.0 Build error

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Operating system and version:
Ubuntu 18.04
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
cmake version 3.10.2

Autoware installation type
Built from source (https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build)

Autoware version : 1.12.0

ROS distribution:
melodic
ROS installation type:
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full

When I did this command colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release I am getting following error basically citysim package failed

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/20012288029825fd73ad0ce240f878d1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327117/autoware-:1.12.0-build-error/) by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2019-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are likely 1 of 3 things going on here:

1. Something from a previous build has been cached and is causing issues. To clean your `colcon` workspace, `cd` to the base of the workspace (above the `src` folder), and run `rm -rf install/ build/ log/`, then re-run the `colcon` command.
2. An incompatibility with the version of Google's Protocol Buffers that you have installed. If you installed them from source, go to the source folder and run `sudo make uninstall` and then try reinstalling with the command `sudo apt install --reinstall protobuf-compiler protobuf-c-compiler libprotoc-dev libprobuf-dev`.
3. An incompatibility with the version of Gazebo that you have installed. Did you install it from source? If so, you'll have to manually remove it (generally `sudo make uninstall` in the source code folder) and re-install it from the repositories (`sudo apt install gazebo9`).

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-27**:
@Maximus I checked all the above mentioned three and did it but I am getting same error

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-06-27**:
Did you use the instructions for the 1.12.0-alpha.2 release or the "bleeding edge" version? Can you go into the citysim folder and do `git fetch && git status` and give me the output?

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-28**:
@Maximus I used the instructions for the 1.12.0-alpha.2 .(wget -O autoware.ai.repos https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/raw/1.12.0-alpha.2/autoware.ai.repos?inline=false ) from this link (https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build)

git fetch && git status of citysim folder

HEAD detached at 27bd05b
nothing to commit, working tree clean.

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-28**:
@Maximus I was able to install somehow but I was unable to run since there is no such directory. When I downloaded previously from github I used to change directory to Autoware/ros and do ./run. but now How i need to run?

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-06-28**:
@sm94 - See if this article helps any: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2496/protobuf-error-on-ubuntu-1804

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-28**:
@Maximus5684- Solved. Thanks

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-06-28**:
@sm94 - Would you mind adding an answer on this question with what you found to be the solution to help others? Thanks.

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-06-28**:
@Maximus Sure. I manually installed google-cartographer and protobuf3 was manually installed in my system and later I installed later by this sudo apt install --reinstall protobuf-compiler protobuf-c-compiler libprotoc-dev libprobuf-dev . So, therefore, it overwrites my system I guess the same error as mentioned in the comments section. If anyone gets this kind of error, I would advise you to clear the caches from the previous build and check if the gazebo is properly installed and mainly check about the protobuf issue. I guess it sorts out everything if you have this error. If anyone has more queries please comment I will try my best to give the best possible solution. Thanks

**Comment by [harshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/32094/harshal/) on 2022-01-25**:
For future reference, in case of having cartographer's system wide protoc/protobuf install: https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2496#issuecomment-658545600